# Cannot read property 'decomposeTextShadow' of undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, javascript-objects

I have the following object:

```
var decomposer = {
        decomposeColor: function(color) {

        },
        removeColor: function(code) {
        },
        decomposeTextShadow: function(code) {

        },

        //This line causes an error
        decomposeBoxShadow:this.decomposeTextShadow,
        decomposeRadius: function(code) {
        }
    };
```

However when I load my page chrome dev tools give me an error saying
`Cannot read property 'decomposeTextShadow' of undefined`
at the line that I have added a comment before in my code.Any ideas?
Even if i try `decomposeBoxShadow:decomposer.decomposeTextShadow`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the code is contained in a strict mode function. In a strict function, `this` is `undefined` if called "normally".

See [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/218196) for a solution to what I believe you are trying to do.

> Even if i try `decomposeBoxShadow:decomposer.decomposeTextShadow`

You are trying to access `decomposer.decomposeTextShadow` during the initialization of the object itself. The object is only assigned to `decomposer` **after** it was created. Therefore, *during* the creation of the object, `decomposer` still has the value `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

In your case `this` not refer to the `decomposer` object. It is `undefined`.